# Joomla 2.5 Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, joomla2.5

I am working on a Joomla website and we are running jomsocial, my question is about the database connection using JFactory. Currently I need information from a database table that is not part of jomsocial so I have to get in the database from a specific page, and I'm doing it wrong. Only because I can't figure out how to make the right way work, so I'm asking here for help. Currently I am just using regular php and mysql_connect.. my DB connection looks like...

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'xxxxxxxx';
$db_pass = 'xxxxxxxx';
$db_database = 'xxxxxxxx';
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Not connected');
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
$user = CFactory::getUser($userid);
$user_plan = mysql_query("SELECT blah FROM blah WHERE blah = '".$user->id."'");
$user_plan_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_plan);
```

And this works, even though its wrong. What I want to do is use

```
JFactory::getDbo();
```

I have found [this page](http://vivavivugeek.blogspot.com/2012/05/joomla-25-classes-for-accessing.html) which describes the syntax well I think, but I can not implement any of the methods described without breaking the page...

Any Ideas or help is greatly appreciated, as it stands right now I have all my secure information in the file and I don't want that I want to use the correct method, because when it comes time to move the site I'm going to have to go change each one of these manually instead of just changing the config file like usual.

Answer (score 0):

The resource you linked to seems fine to me , you will need to post some specific errors.